# Simple slider not working & Absolute positioning issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I had an issue with the absolute positioning, of the elements that I was manipulating via Jquery. However I managed to solve the issue by positioning the elements at `left:0px;`.

In the process I also discovered a problem that I have no idea how to fix. This problem can be replicated using the JS Fiddle by simply changing the Jq Framework to 1.10.1 and updating the page then running it. its as if the code breaks and only partially works. I'm having the same issue within the page that i have built it on.

I have;

- Checked all links, to ensure they are not broken or spelled incorrectly.
- Scanned all the code for syntax errors.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qEjXj/974/)

here is the script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".slide-one").show();
    $(".slide-two").hide();

    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        $(".slide-one").toggle( "slide", 1000 );
    });
    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        $(".slide-two").toggle( "slide", 1000 );
    });

});
```

Comment: what is the problem , why dont you want to use absolute ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek I was over thinking the issue it appears, its been a long day. I solved my problem by using only the `left:0px;` rule. I did however discover another issue in the process. Check the question for an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link to jQueryUI separately when using jQuery1.10 in jsFiddle.  This fixed your new problem for me.

Additionally, but not what is causing the problem, you only need to bind `.click` to `.show_hide` once.

```
$('.show_hide').click(function () {
    $(".slide-one").toggle( "slide", 1000 );
    $(".slide-two").toggle( "slide", 1000 );
});
```

Here is an updated fiddle: <kbd>[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/qEjXj/981/)</kbd>

Comment: I figured it might be the UI, after doing some research. but was unawares of only binding the click once. I have recently decided to change from a click event to a timed event every 15 or so seconds would you know how to do this?

Comment: Never used it myself, but javascript has a function called `setInterval()` that lets you perform something at intervals.

Comment: Yes after some research I managed to complete the timed events. I was originally trying to use `.delay` but that was not quite working the way I needed it to. Thanks again for all your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `.toggle()` is wrong, the [API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) says:

```
.toggle( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

So it's duration first then the easing type. As *Patrick Allen* points out, if you don't load jQueryUI you will not have a "slide" easing function -- you can see the undefined function call in the console.

I think you probably want to use:

```
$(".slide-one").slideToggle( 1000 );
```

to get the effect you're looking for. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/hjNxx/).